# how to set an OCR language in Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I need to upload image into Google Drive including the OCR feature.

The problem with the `setOcrLanguage` method. I need to specify Hebrew language and based on ISO 639-1 codes its should be "heb".

I'm getting the response

```
 "code" : 400,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "location" : "ocrLanguage",
      "locationType" : "parameter",
      "message" : "Invalid Value",
      "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
```

Any idea what should be the code or where I can get the list of avaliable codes?

Comment: i tried "he","iw" and "Heb" none of them worked

Comment: its look like there is a bug in the api, the code should be iw.this code generate an error "     File file = service.files().insert(metaFile, mediaFile).setOcrLanguage("iw").setOcr(true).execute();